# Can't load image from MySQL to React.js using Node.js

Tags: mysql, node.js, reactjs

So I'm trying to get data from my database to display products in React.js using Node.js.
The problem is that my image from my MySQL database doesn`t load up.

[Here is my database][1]

Code from the Nodejs server:

```js
const cors = require('cors');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const { response } = require('express');

const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
const saltRounds = 10;

dotenv.config({ path: './.env' });

const app = express();
app.use(express.json());
app.use(
    cors({
        origin: [ 'http://localhost:3001' ],
        methods: [ 'GET', 'POST' ],
        credentials: true
    })
);


app.get('/products', async (req, res) => {
    db.query('SELECT * FROM products', (error, results) => {
        if (error) res.send(error);
        res.send(results);
    });
});
```

And the data is display on port:3000/products like this

```json
[
  {
    "productID": 1000,
    "productName": "Polyfloral Honey",
    "price": 12.99,
    "description": "Enjoy the goodness of fresh honey all year, with this deeply refreshing nectar.",
    "quantity": 100,
    "image": {
    "type": "Buffer",
    "data": [
    137,
    80,
    78,
    71,
    13,
    10,
    26,
    10,
    0,
    0,....
]
```

React code:
ReactJs part In App.js:

```js
    useEffect(() => {
        Axios.get('http://localhost:3000/products').then((response) => {
            setProductsList(response.data);
            console.log(response.data);
        });
    }, []);
```

And I send it to:

```
    const Ourwork = ({ setProductsList, productsList }) => {
    
    return (
        <Work exit="exit" variants={pageAnimation} initial="hidden" animate="show">
            {productsList.map((product) => (
                <Product
                    productName={product.productName}
                    description={product.description}
                    price={product.price}
                    image={product.image.data}
                    url={product.url}
                />
            ))}
        </Work>
    );
};
```

Where I tried to access the image from database:

```
const Product = ({ productName, url, price, image }) => {
    
    return (
        <ProductStyle>
            <Link to={url}>
                <SmallCircle onMouseOver={Scale} onMouseLeave={UnScale}>
                    <img src={image} />
                </SmallCircle>
            </Link>
            <h2>{productName}</h2>
            <h4>{price}</h4>
        </ProductStyle>
    );
};
```

The problem is that `product.image` is undifined.

At first I thought that it is 431 Error, but I updated Node and NPM to latest versions and used `--max-http-header-size=16384` so I don't have problems here.

I tried to convert image to base64 but it doesn't work but I still can't read the image source.

I'm stuck here for 3 days and any help would be welcomed!

Comment: Could you please post your implementation as text, instead of images?

Comment: I edited the post as you sugested